# LaTeX table positioning at specific point in code

Tags: position, latex, positioning, tabular

I try to keep the following table at the same position as it appears in my LaTeX code.

```
\begin{table*}[h]
\makebox[\linewidth]{
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c |}
        \hline
        Datum & [Tage] & [Tage]\\
        \hline
        01.03.2010 & 1 nach \fullmoon & 5 bis \leftmoon\\
        15.03.2010 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\newmoon}\\
        10.12.2009 & 1 nach \leftmoon & 6 vor \newmoon\\
        09.03.2009 & 5 nach \rightmoon & 2 vor \fullmoon\\
        07.01.2010 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\leftmoon}\\
        14.12.2010 & 1 nach \rightmoon & 7 vor \fullmoon\\
        02.04.2009 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\rightmoon}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\caption{Niedrigste relative Intensität. \fullmoon Vollmond, \newmoon Neumond, \rightmoon{} zunehmender Halbmond, \leftmoon abnehmender Halbmond}  
\label{table10}
\end{table*}
```

So I tried it with [H], but this lets the table disappear. Also trying something from another thread

```
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
```

does not work. Any advice ?

Comment: Lots of advices here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020

Answer (score 1):

If there's enough space at that point of the output page to accommodate that table, then this couple of tweaks should probably do:

1. change `{table*}` to `{table}`
2. change `[h]` to `[h!]`

The `\makebox{...}` environment should also be done away with to avoid complications.

If LaTeX isn't able to place the table at that point, it gives a warning, but the table should never disappear, then.